# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel slide duration

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

In the Twitter Bootstrap Carousel, how can I make a particular slide to have a different duration than others?

I can change the whole slider duration with the "interval" parameter, but don't know how to set a custom duration for a particular slide.

Comment: I know that it's more than a year, but i am very happy that i found a easy solution for this issue witch is still a problem even today. I hope my answere is helpful for you.

Comment: Also see [Bootstrap custom carousel intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047620/custom-carousel-intervals?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap 3.1 carousel don't allow diferent duration for each slide, but it offers **one method** and **one event** that we can use in order to ahieve this.

We will use the `slid.bs.carousel` event to detect when the carousel has completed its slide transition and the `.carousel('pause')` option to stop the carousel from cycling through items.

We will use this attribute `data-interval="x"` on each carousel item with different time duration, so our html will look like this for example:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item" data-interval="3000">
        <img src="Url 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-interval="6000">
        <img src="Url 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-interval="9000">
        <img src="Url 3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, all we have to do is to:

1. detect when a new item is displayed using the `slid.bs.carousel`
   event
2. check his duration
3. pause the carousel using `.carousel('pause')`
4. set a timeout with the duration of the item and after the duration
   completed we should unpause the carousel

The javascript code will look like this:

```
var t;

var start = $('#myCarousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 1000});", start-1000);

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {   
     clearTimeout(t);  
     var duration = $(this).find('.active').attr('data-interval');

     $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
     t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel();", duration-1000);
})

$('.carousel-control.right').on('click', function(){
    clearTimeout(t);   
});

$('.carousel-control.left').on('click', function(){
    clearTimeout(t);   
});
```

As you can see, we are forced at the begining to add a starting interval and i've set it to 1000ms but i remove it each time i pause the carousel `duration-1000`. I've used the lines below to resolve the first item problem because that item was not caught by the `slid event`.

```
var start = $('#myCarousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 1000});", start-1000);
```

I also noticed that if the user presses the arrows, the timeout is going crazy, that's why i clear the timeout each time the user press on the left and right arrow.

Here is my live example http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/52KBT/, hope this response was helpful for you.

Comment: I tried this but could not get `carousel('pause')` to work at all in the slide.bs.carousel event. I tried about everything possible and it never paused - just kept going on in the cycle. My solution was very similar to yours instead using `carousel('next')` along with `setTimeout` and `data-interval` attribute. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You are welcome. The carousel('pause') option is working in all cases, you can check the documentation here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage . Most probably you have some errors in your code. It should definetly work without any problem. If you strip your code and keep just the carousel, or even if you try a blank example into jsfiddle, you will see it work. I don't recomand to use setTimeout because if you press the arrows, the duration might go crazy. Anytime is best to use the bootstrap carousel options.

Comment: @AndyBrudtkuhl  how did you manage? how you set time for first slide

Answer (score 0):

You need to set interval in main div as data-interval tag. So it is working fine and you can give different time to different slides.

```
<!--main div -->
<div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="100" id="carousel-example-generic">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div role="listbox" class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
      <a class="carousel-image" href="#">
        <img alt="image" src="image.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please give an example of a different intervals for different slides.

Comment: Don't see how this would work for different intervals on different slides... but it solved what I was trying to do which is change the interval over ALL slides. So thanks for the simple post for this.

Answer (score -1):

I could not get `carousel('pause')` to work at all inside the bootstrap event handlers. I'm not sure why - potentially it was due to dynamically rendering the slides with KnockoutJS or perhaps a bug in Bootstrap *(I'm guessing it's my code)*.

So in order to set an individual slide's interval independent of it's friends in the carousel I used the `slid.bs.carousel` event bubbled up in Bootstrap along with using `setTimeout` to set the interval based on the item's `data-interval` attribute and manually calling the `carousel('next')` method.

**JS**

```
// slide event
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');
    var currentIndex = carouselData.getActiveIndex();

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('.carousel').carousel('next');
    }, $(carouselData.$items[currentIndex]).data('interval'));
});

// init carousel
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
});

// set initial timeout for active slide data-interval
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel('next');
}, $('.carousel .active').data('interval'));
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div id="slide1" class="item active" data-interval="5000">{{content}}</div>
    <div id="slide2" class="item" data-interval="10000">{{content}}</div>
    <div id="slide3" class="item" data-interval="10000">{{content}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example `#slide1` will be the initial slide in your carousel and show for 5 seconds. After 5 seconds it will slide to `#slide2`.

`#slide2` will pause for 10 seconds before sliding to `#slide3`. And so on. And so on...

Answer (score -2):

If you still haven't found a solution, I have modified the Bootstrap **carousel.js** to add this functionality.

1. Add optional attribute (**data-interval**) to "item" class element.

   `<div class="active item" data-interval="6000">`
2. Modify **carousel.js**

   - **Add flag to determine first cycle**

     ```
     var Carousel = function (element, options) {
     this.$element    = $(element)
     this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators')
     this.options     = options
     this.paused      =
     this.sliding     =
     this.interval    =
     this.$active     =
     this.$items      = null
     //[TODO Kevin] Added - BEGIN
     this.isFirstCycle= true
     //[TODO Kevin] Added - BEGIN

     this.options.pause == 'hover' && this.$element
     .on('mouseenter', $.proxy(this.pause, this))
     .on('mouseleave', $.proxy(this.cycle, this))
     }
     ```
   - **Modify CYCLE function**

     ```
      Carousel.prototype.cycle =  function (e) {
      e || (this.paused = false)

      this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)
      //[TODO Kevin] Modified - BEGIN
      //this.options.interval && !this.paused && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))

      if (this.options.interval && !this.paused) {
        var $active = this.$element.find('.item.active');

        /**CUSTOM ITEM INTERVAL**/
        if ($active.data('interval')) {
          var customInterval;

          /*On First Cycle*/
          if(this.isFirstCycle) {
            //Get ACTIVE ITEM interval
            customInterval = $active.data('interval');
            this.isFirstCycle = false;

          /*On Suceeding Cycles*/
          } else {
            //Get NEXT ITEM interval
            var $next = $active['next']();

            if (!$next.length) {
              if (!this.options.wrap) return this
              $next = this.$element.find('.item')['first']()
            }

            customInterval = $next.data('interval');
          }

          this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), customInterval);

        /**DEFAULT INTERVAL**/
        } else {
          this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval);
        }
      }
      //[TODO Kevin] Modified - END

      return this
      }
     ```

Sample: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qw4QY/1/)

Comment: Almost there but you don't want to modify Bootstrap core (or at least you shouldn't want to)