# How do I change slide time in SJ Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, carousel

I need to change the amount of time a slide is being shown in SJ Carousel. This is not the transition or fading time. I'm not talking about the time it takes to go from one slide to the next, but how much time the slides are shown.

How can I do this? I read similar forums and nothing helped. I did change this code in the CSS file in Joomla, as well as in the bootstrap.min file to be defined as 1 second instead of 0.6, but that only changes the transition time from one slide to the other...

`carousel-inner > .item {
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
        -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
        -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
        transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;`
}

Can anyone help me? 
Thank you!

Comment: SJ Carousel is an extension for Joomla, WordPress, etc. How does it relate to Bootstrap? For Joomla, there's apparently an `interval` setting: http://www.smartaddons.com/joomla/extensions/extension-user-guides/709-sj-carousel-userguide

Comment: The truth is - I don't know. I looked up this subject in the forums here and found several suggestions about the edits in bootstrap and people were commenting with "Thank you, it helped." So naturally I assumed it has something to do with it...

Here's one of those articles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744295/how-do-i-change-slide-time-in-sj-carousel

Comment: You've linked to your own question. :-) Please tell us where you're implementing JS Carousel. It's critical to your question. Joomla? Somewhere else?

Comment: Oh snap! Hahaha, that was dumb. Here are the two links I saw:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236516/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-slide-duration

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792000/how-to-change-bootstraps-carousel-transition-from-slide-to-fade

Yes, I am implementing it in Joomla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [**documentation**](http://www.smartaddons.com/joomla/extensions/extension-user-guides/709-sj-carousel-userguide) for the SJ Carousel Joomla extension. Under **Effect Options**, you'll simply set the duration (in milliseconds) in the **Interval** field in your module.

[image: screenshot of config options]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I did not have the same SJ Carousel that you're talking about. But then I installed the one you showed me the documentation for and I was able to change the slide transition time! The SJ Carousel I had installed did not have Effect Options. Thank you so much for your help!