# Custom Carousel Intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3, with jQuery is there a way to sort by the index of my carousel and add custom intervals of each slide so that I can have one slide 10000ms and another 500ms etc?

I know you can set the data-interval attribute but this sets the speed for all slides as you can't add a custom interval attribute to each item.

```
data-interval="3000"
```

My carousel is setup like this:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">

     <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
        <a href="#">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <a href="#" >
            <img class="img-responsive" src="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used bootstrap's carousel, flexslider, nivo, owl, bx, and a few others none of them have this ability.

Comment: @Christina You can still get it to happen, just requires a bit of thinking outside the box.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236516/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-slide-duration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a custom attribute that denotes how long the slide should be visible for, pull that out for the active item on the `slide.bs.carousel` or `slid.bs.carousel` events (whichever you prefer/works best for you), then set it as a timeout to go to the next slide.

```js
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
  var interval = $('div.item.active').attr('duration');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel('next');
  }, interval);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active" duration="3000">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="..." />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        First
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" duration="2000">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="..." />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Second
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" duration="1000">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="..." />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Third
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" duration="500">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="..." />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Fourth
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I expect this does not work when one custom interval is larger and the other one smaller than the default (or set interval) which can probably fixed by setting the interval option to `false`

Answer (score 2):

The solution given by @MattD seems to work well, alternatively you could overwrite the slide function of the carousel plugin bu using the following code:

```
<script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
<script>
  $.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.cycle = function (e) {

    e || (this.paused = false)
    this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

    this.options.interval
      && !this.paused
      && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.$element.find('.item.active').data('interval') || this.options.interval))

    return this
  }
</script>
```

The above enables you to set the interval per slide leveraging the `data-interval` attribute as shown below:

```
<div class="item" data-interval="500">
```

Comment: hey bro.. even this has an issue.. the interval for first and second slide remains same.. please check..

Comment: you should set the interval for each item

Comment: Thanks Bass, Updated for Bootstrap 4.x: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969734/171456

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Bass didn't quite work for me. It was actually taking the `interval` of the slide BEFORE, so my updated version is:

```js
    function overwriteBootstrapCarouselCycleFunction() {
      $.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.cycle = function (e) {

        e || (this.paused = false)
        this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

        var element_to_slide;
        var duration;


        if (this.$element.find('.item.next').size() === 1) { // once the first slide has started the interval until the next call is on the slide with the 'next' class
          element_to_slide = this.$element.find('.item.next')
        } else {
          element_to_slide = this.$element.find('.item.active') // just before the cycle starts, there is no 'next' but the first slide is marked active, use that
        }

        duration = element_to_slide.data('interval')                          // if the element has a pre-configured interval use it
        if(typeof duration === "undefined") duration = this.options.interval  // otherwise use the default for the slideshow

      
        this.options.interval
          && !this.paused
          && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), duration ))

        $.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.overwritten = true

        return this
      }
    }


    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      if (!$.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.overwritten)
        overwriteBootstrapCarouselCycleFunction()

      var id = '#{carousel_id}'

      $('#' + id + ' #pause-control').click(function(){
        pauseSlideshow(id)
      })

      $('#' + id + ' #play-control').click(function(){
        playSlideshow(id)
      })
    })
```