# individual data intervals bootstrap carousel 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set an individual data interval for each slide on my bootstrap 4 carousel. I have tried a few other snippets of javascript, however they don't seem to work with my code, such as [Bootstrap 4 Carousel-stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968181/bootstrap-4-carousel-individual-data-interval-on-each-slide)

Could anyone please suggest something, any help is appreciated.

```css
#top-bootstrap-slider{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgb(15,36,62);
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.carousel-item{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="top-bootstrap-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
   Testimonial 1
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
     Testimonial 2
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
     Testimonial 3
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made an implementation based on the Zim's answers from this: [Bootstrap 4 Carousel: Individual data-interval on each slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968181/bootstrap-4-carousel-individual-data-interval-on-each-slide), and it is working good, except for the start point of the carousel (i.e. the first slide uses the default interval on the first iteration). For use this extension, you have to add the `data-interval` attribute to each `carousel-item` setting on it the milliseconds of the interval. Check next example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Extend the Bootstrap carousel implementation.

    $.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.cycle = function (event)
    {
        if (!event)
            this._isPaused = false;

        if (this._interval)
        {
            clearInterval(this._interval);
            this._interval = null;
        }

        if (this._config.interval && !this._isPaused)
        {
            var item = $('.carousel-item-next');
            var newInterval = item.data('interval') || this._config.interval;

            this._interval = setInterval(
                (document.visibilityState ? this.nextWhenVisible : this.next).bind(this),
                newInterval
            );
        }
    };
});
```

```css
#top-bootstrap-slider{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgb(15,36,62);
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.carousel-item{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="top-bootstrap-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="1000">
      Testimonial 1
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="2000">
      Testimonial 2
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="5000">
      Testimonial 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, in case the previous don't work, you can wrap the code inside `<script>` and `</script>` tags after the including of the **Bootstrap** files, like this:

```css
#top-bootstrap-slider{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgb(15,36,62);
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.carousel-item{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.cycle = function (event)
{
    if (!event)
        this._isPaused = false;

    if (this._interval)
    {
        clearInterval(this._interval);
        this._interval = null;
    }

    if (this._config.interval && !this._isPaused)
    {
        var item = $('.carousel-item-next');
        var newInterval = item.data('interval') || this._config.interval;

        this._interval = setInterval(
            (document.visibilityState ? this.nextWhenVisible : this.next).bind(this),
            newInterval
        );
    }
};
</script>

<div id="top-bootstrap-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="1000">
      Testimonial 1
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="2000">
      Testimonial 2
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="5000">
      Testimonial 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Update for support to multiple carousels**

The next example shows how to do a correct implementation for support multiple carousels. Basically we need to use next line when selecting the `item`:

```
var item = $(this._element).find('.carousel-item-next');
```

```css
#top-bootstrap-slider{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgb(15,36,62);
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 10px;
}

#top-bootstrap-slider2{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    background: skyblue;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.carousel-item{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.cycle = function (event)
{
    if (!event)
        this._isPaused = false;

    if (this._interval)
    {
        clearInterval(this._interval);
        this._interval = null;
    }

    if (this._config.interval && !this._isPaused)
    {
        // This next line does the trick.
        var item = $(this._element).find('.carousel-item-next');
        var newInterval = item.data('interval') || this._config.interval;

        this._interval = setInterval(
            (document.visibilityState ? this.nextWhenVisible : this.next).bind(this),
            newInterval
        );
    }
};
</script>

<div id="top-bootstrap-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="1000">
      Testimonial 1
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="2000">
      Testimonial 2
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="5000">
      Testimonial 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="top-bootstrap-slider2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="3000">
      Testimonial 4
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="1000">
      Testimonial 5
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="1000">
      Testimonial 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi D.Smania, thank you for your help, it seems to work in stack overflow, but when I try and insert the code into codepen, it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong? [Codepen](https://codepen.io/chenius/pen/jQojBW)

Comment: Is strange, just manage to get it work placing the code inside `<script>...</script>` on the **HTML** markup. Check: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QJXpdg). So, just use the option that works on your local server.

Comment: Is there a way to add data-intervals to more than one carousel, because this only works with one, whereas I want to add another four carousels.

Comment: @Chenius I have updated with a fix for this support, check the answer now.