# Real Time interval modification for each slides

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

For a project, I want to modify (in real Time) each slide interval (separately) in my carousel, with some basic form inputs.

```
<input type="number" id="slide1">
```

I follow this link :  [individual data intervals bootstrap carousel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635583/individual-data-intervals-bootstrap-carousel-4)

```
$.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.cycle = function (event)
{
    if (!event)
        this._isPaused = false;

    if (this._interval)
    {
        clearInterval(this._interval);
        this._interval = null;
    }

    if (this._config.interval && !this._isPaused)
    {
        var item = $('.carousel-item-next');
        var newInterval = item.data('interval') || this._config.interval;

        this._interval = setInterval(
        (document.visibilityState ? this.nextWhenVisible : this.next).bind(this),
        newInterval);
     }
};
```

and everything works fine with my different intervals.

But now... No way to change intervals after carousel initialization.

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

**The problem was my old version of Bootstrap...**

Comment: When changing the carousel after initialization, you will need to dispose the current carousel and re-initialize the carousel with the new options [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#carouseldispose](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#carouseldispose)

Comment: Thank you but I don't really understand how to do that. Do you have any exemple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use the `data-interval` tag attribute and manipulate the times that way. See snippet below

```js
function formCheck(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  let $slide1 = $("#durSlide1").val();
  if ($slide1 > 0) {
    $("#slide1").attr("data-interval", $slide1 * 1000);
  } else {
    $("#slide1").removeAttr("data-interval");
  }
  let $slide2 = $("#durSlide2").val();
  if ($slide2 > 0) {
    $("#slide2").attr("data-interval", $slide2 * 1000);
  } else {
    $("#slide2").removeAttr("data-interval");
  }
  let $slide3 = $("#durSlide3").val();
  if ($slide3 > 0) {
    $("#slide3").attr("data-interval", $slide3 * 1000);
  } else {
    $("#slide3").removeAttr("data-interval");
  }
  $(".carousel").carousel("next");
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="form-row mx-3">
      <div class="column">
        <input id="durSlide1" name="durSlide1" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Duration for Slide #1">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <input id="durSlide2" name="durSlide2" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Duration for Slide #2">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <input id="durSlide3" name="durSlide3" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Duration for Slide #3">
      </div>
      <button type="button" onclick="formCheck(event)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div id="slide1" class="carousel-item active" data-interval="2000">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img">
        <title>Placeholder</title>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#fff" dy=".3em">First slide</text></svg>
      </div>
      <div id="slide2" class="carousel-item" data-interval="2000">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img">
        <title>Placeholder</title>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#fff" dy=".3em">Second slide</text></svg>
      </div>
      <div id="slide3" class="carousel-item" data-interval="2000">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#fff" dy=".3em">Third slide</text>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. But, this only work during the 2 first slides, after this time, if I change the interval,  the new value appears but doesn't work...

Comment: There was a mistake that I posted on the first snippet code that the third slide was using the input box 2 value. I have corrected the issue within a few minutes of posting the code, but you might still be running the old code. Try doing a hard refresh on the browser and running the snippet again. Also, what browser are you using?