# In the bootstrap4 carousel, how can I make particular slides stay longer?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

When active, some slides in my carousel should have an interval of 1000 before transitioning to the next slide. Others should have an interval of 5000. How can I get the active slide in jQuery, to make changes to the carousel interval? I also want to run scripts depending on which slide is active.

The slideshow is around 30 slides long, and is informational. The constant static slide transition time makes it harder to absorb the information displayed on the slides. I want to trigger additional animations and effects based on the current slide shown; and also to vary the tempo of the slideshow depending on how much text is on the current slide.

`if ($('.carousel').carousel(5)) {
 playa = false;
 setTimeout(playa = true, 6000);
 }` 
But this just jumps the carousel to slide 5;

`$('.carousel').on('slide', function (e) {
    var slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index();console.log(slideFrom);
     alert("respond!")
    }`
This didn't give any response

I half-tried this - but I think slide.bs.carousel is bs3 only:
  `$('#Carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
    var id = ev.relatedTarget.id;
    switch (id) {
      case "1":
        console.log("1");
        break;
      case "2":
        console.log("2");
        break;
      case "3":
        console.log("3");`
Something like the following actually did change the value of data-interval, but not the speed at which the slides change.

`aboutGo = () => {
    $('.carousel').carousel(0);
    $('.carousel').attr({ 'data-interval': '2000' });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 Carousel: Individual data-interval on each slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968181/bootstrap-4-carousel-individual-data-interval-on-each-slide)

Answer (score 0):

I can work with the following solution for now:

```
slideEvent = () => {
  switch (slideNumber) {

  case 0: console.log("First poem is...");
    $('.carousel').carousel(0);
    wait = 6000;
    break;

  case 1: console.log("sampla");
    wait = 4000;
    $('.carousel').carousel(1);

    break;
  case 2: console.log("according to legends");
    $('.carousel').carousel(2);
    break;

  case 3: console.log("nexto");
    $('.carousel').carousel(3);

    break;
  case 4: console.log("and then...");
    wait = 1000;
    $('.carousel').carousel(4);

    break;

  case 5: console.log("and then...");
    wait = 4000;
    $('.carousel').carousel(5);

    break;
  case 6: console.log("and then...");
    $('.carousel').carousel(6);

    break;
  case 7: console.log("and then...");
    $('.carousel').carousel(7);

    break;
  case 8: console.log("and then...");
    $('.carousel').carousel(8);

    break;
  case 9: console.log("and then...");
    $('.carousel').carousel(9);

    break;
  case 10: console.log("and then...");
    $('.carousel').carousel(10);

    break;

  default: break;

}
```

}

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: false,
    interval: 0,

})


var slideNumber = 0;
var wait = 4000;
changeSlide = () => {

  setTimeout(changeSlide, wait);
  slideEvent();
  slideNumber++;
  ;
}
changeSlide();
```